# getVersion not showing

Tags: solidity, remix, contract-deployment

I am following a solidity tutorial and I can seem to make the getVerison bottom on remix to work. In the tutorial it shows the version and in mine, after deployment it does not show anything. maybe its because I am supposed to select "Injected Web 3" on environment (but I don't have that one in my remix version). I tried selecting "Inject Provider - Metamask" but it goes back to Remix VM (London) and I get the message/error "Please make sure the injected provider is unlocked (e.g Metamask)." My contract is the following:

```
pragma solidity >=0.6.6 <0.9.0;
import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/interfaces/AggregatorV3Interface.sol";
contract FundMe {
    mapping(address => uint256) public addressToAmountFunded; 
    function fund() public payable {
        addressToAmountFunded[msg.sender] += msg.value;
        //what the ETH -> USD conversion rate
    }
    function getVersion () public view returns (uint256) {
        AggregatorV3Interface priceFeed = AggregatorV3Interface(0xD4a33860578De61DBAbDc8BFdb98FD742fA7028e);
        return priceFeed.version();
    }
}
```

Comment: Is your metamask installed and unlocked?

Comment: Yes, I have installed metamask... but I don't know how to lock it or unlock it... I did connect the wallet to remix...

Comment: Setup your Metamask first, get some test ETH, and then connect it with your remix IDE. Also, make sure the address in `AggregatorV3Interface()` belongs to that same chain.

Comment: I refreshed the browser and it solved the problem.